# Chain find_or_create_by with update_counters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

Is it possible to chain **find_or_create_by** with **update_counters**?

I'm trying to **increment the current value of "points"**, and only for specific records which would need to be created if they do not exist yet. So it would be just 1 DB hit if the record exists.

Something like this:

```
Point.where(user_id:4).find_or_create_by(topic_id:107).update_counters(points: 5)
```

**CONTEXT**:
Users gain **Points** depending on the **Topics** they do contribute (which could be many so I'm trying to reduce the 2 queries to just 1). Point belongs to User and Topic, so if the user has not contributed to a topic yet, a new Point record needs to be created to store those points *(user_id, topic_id, points)*; otherwise the points of the existing record would just increment. I use `increment!(:points,5)` but it hits the DB twice (select+update). **update_counters** works with just 1 update query, but it seems like not in this case as its syntax does not allow me to include the conditions I need.

This works but it hits the DB twice:

```
Point.where(user_id:4).find_or_create_by(topic_id:107).increment!(:points,5)
```

Comment: In theory you might be able to achieve an effect like this with a ton of effort and a really good understanding of sql but the simple answer is no.

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency there are some other ways to string together activerecord relations which might save you a rather large number of sql queries.  Could you put a bit more context so that we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @user3334690. I just updated the question with the context. Yep, I'm looking for efficiency. Thanks for your thoughts :-)

Comment: The way that line is written the only thing I can think of to get it down would be a stored procedure (which doesn't necessarily actually get it any more efficient just moves around who is processing it).  It sounds to me like you're iterating over the topic_ids when calling this line?  You could reduce the number of total queries by starting with all existing points like: `points_by_topic = Point.where(user_id: 4, topic_id: topic_ids).index_by(&:topic_id)` then iterating over topic_id.  That would mean you have one select total and one update/insert per topic.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes you'll probably also want to look at creating an index for topic_id together with user_id if you haven't already.  There is a code-review stack exchange http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and you might do well to ask there about making your action more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @user3334690